# how to bind multiple models to a single view in spring web flow?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

**Situation :** I am developing a spring MVC webapp and using spring web flow and tiles framework . I have two tables in DB `customer` and `customerAdress` and i have two model classes for them named `customerModel` and `customerAdressModel` .

Now in my flow.xml i have the following `view-state` :

```
<var name = "cust" class = "com.model.CustomerModel"/> 

<view-state id = "customerViewState" view = "customer" model = "cust">

        <transition on="next" to="customerData"/>

    </view-state>
```

Tile framework resolves the view `customer` to appropriate `customer.jsp` which is shown below :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"     
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

<div>
<form id="Form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-   
inline">    
    <div class="inputDiv">

            <label class="inputLabel"> Name :</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">           



            <label class="inputLabel">Email :</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">

    </div>              
    <input type="button" id="forwardButton" value="Next"/>
</form>
</div>

</body>
<script>

$("#forwardButton").click(function(){

$("#WlDetailsForm").attr('action','${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=next');
    $("#WlDetailsForm").submit();

});
</script>
</html>
```

**Problem :** Now the form specified in `customer.jsp` has some input fields that contains value of properties of `customerAdressModel` .Thus i want to bind `customerModel` as well as `customerAdressModel` to the same view state `customerViewState`. How do i do that , i went through spring DOC but couldnt find anything , please help !

**Note :** i cant modify my sql tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create composite model DTO

```
public class CompositeModelDto {

    private CustomerModel suctomer;

    private CustomerAddressModel address;

    //setters ang getters ...

}
```

And use it as a view state model

```
<var name = "cust" class = "com.model.CustomerModel"/>
<var name = "address" class = "com.model.CustomerAddressModel"/>
<var name = "customerDto" class = "com.model.CompositeModelDto"/>

<view-state id = "customerViewState" view = "customer" model = "customerDto">
    <on-entry>
        <set name="customerDto.customer" value="cust"/>
        <set name="customerDto.address" value="address"/>
    </on-entry>

    <transition on="next" to="customerData"/>

</view-state>
```

---

**UPDATE**

For views I'd suggest using Spring's form tag library. Define taglib

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

and replace form in your jsp with

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=next" modelAttribute="customerDto">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="customer.name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="customer.name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="customer.email">Email</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="customer.email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="address.addressLine1">Address Line 1</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="address.addressLine1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</form:form>
```

Comment: what are the set statements doing , why are they required ?

Comment: @varunsinghal `set` statement sets `value` expression result to the attribute defined in `name`. `<set name="customerDto.customer" value="cust"/>` means `customerDto.setCustomer(cust)`. Both sets are required to set customer and address into DTO in order to refer them in jsp.

Comment: one doubt , i have a buisness service that takes customerModel as input parameter and then inserts that input parameter in the customer Table . how would i achieve that here ? can i do like this : cusomerBuisness.createCustomer(customerDto.cust) ? please help !

Comment: @varunsinghal Yes, you can.

Comment: i am a little confused how to refer `customerModel` variable of  `customerModelDto` in JSP and then pass this variable as input to `customerModel` buisness service , if you could shed some light on this it would be very helpful

Comment: @varunsinghal I don't now Tiles but I believe it's just templating framework and it doesn't bring something new into jsp. If before in jsp  you refer to customer attribute using something like `${model.name}` then now you need `${model.customer.name}` and for address `${model.address.postalCode}`

Comment: i never referred to any model in my jsp , i only wrote `model="cust"` in my `<view-tag>` and it would automaticallly bind the inputs in `customer.jsp` , but now since i am using `model=customerDto` in view state binding is not occuring , how do i refer `customerDto.customer` in the jsp ?

Comment: @varunsinghal Could you add jsp to the question?

Comment: code posted , please tell now how do i bind this form to model `customerDto.customer`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515008/how-to-store-value-returned-by-a-business-service-in-a-variable-in-spring-web-fl can you please solve this , it will take you  a mintute