# how to store value returned by a business service in a variable in spring web flow?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

**Situation :** I am developing a spring mvc web flow app , in that i have two tables `customer` and `customerAdress` and two corresponding models : `customerModel` and `customerAdressModel` , now following is my flow.xml :

```
   <var name="customer" class="com.model.Customer"/>
   <var name="customerAdress" class="com.model.CustomerAdress"/>
   <var name="id">

   <view-state id="customer" view="customerView.jsp" model="customer">

    <transition on="next" to="customerAdress"/>
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="customerAdress" view="customerAdressView.jsp" model="customerAdress">

    <transition on="next" to="insertCustomer"/>
    </view-state>

   <action-state id="insertCustomer">
    <evaluate expression="Buisness.insertCustomer(customer)"/>
    <evaluate expression="Buisness.fetchCustomerId(customer)" result="id"/>
    <evaluate expression="Buisness.insertCustomerAdress(id,cutomerAdress)"/>
    </action-state>
```

Now `insertCustomer` inserts customer , `fetchCustomerId` fetches customer's id and `insertCusotomerAdress` inserts adresses of customer by `id`

**Problem :** My problem is this code is not working , specifically `insertCustomerAdress` is not working , i think i have done some mistake in decalring `id` or assigning buisness service's value to `id` , can somebody please tell me proper syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

By default action state executes only first action. To execute a chain of actions use [Named actions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/actions.html#named-actions).

```
<action-state id="insertCustomer">
    <evaluate expression="Buisness.insertCustomer(customer)">
        <attribute name="name" value="insertCustomer" />
    </evaluate>
    <evaluate expression="Buisness.fetchCustomerId(customer)" result="id">
        <attribute name="name" value="fetchCustomerId" />
    </evaluate>
    <evaluate expression="Buisness.insertCustomerAdress(id,cutomerAdress)">
        <attribute name="name" value="insertCustomerAdress" />
    </evaluate>
    <transition on="insertCustomerAdress.success" to="[state id to transit]" />
</action-state>
```